# ios imageview animation using array causes semaphore_wait_trap

Tags: ios, animation, imageview

I'm trying to animate an imageview by providing it with an array of images. These images have been extracted from a spritesheet having lots of images one after the other.

Here is my code:

```
-(NSMutableArray*)getIndividualImagesFromImage:(UIImage*)collectionOfEmoticonImages

{

NSMutableArray *imagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

//Let's find out the total number of images in this big image
int totalEmoticonImages = collectionOfEmoticonImages.size.width/WIDTH_HEIGHT_OF_EMOTICONS;

for(int emoticonIndex = 0; emoticonIndex < totalEmoticonImages; emoticonIndex++)
{
    //crop the image at each index and put smaller images in the array
    UIImage *croppedImage = [[UIImage alloc] init];
    croppedImage = [self cropImage:collectionOfEmoticonImages atIndex:emoticonIndex];
    [imagesArray addObject:croppedImage];
}

return imagesArray;

}

-(void)getEmoticonImageViewAnimating:(NSInteger)index
{
    imagesArray = [self getIndividualImagesFromImage:[emoticonsPNGImages objectAtIndex:index]];

    //Animate using the images in imagesArray
    emoImageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithArray:imagesArray];
    emoImageView.animationDuration = 2;
    emoImageView.animationRepeatCount = 1;

    [emoImageView startAnimating];
    [self performSelector:@selector(animationDidFinish) withObject:nil
           afterDelay:emoImageView.animationDuration];
}
```

Everything works fine if I comment [emoImageView startAnimating]; line. But with this statement, animation works fine for 6 times  but then I get a semaphore_wait_trap on trying to run it 7th time.

Any pointers?

Comment: How do you start the animation for another time?

Comment: This code executes on a button click, so the animation starts again when the button is clicked. Clicking it 6 times works fine

Comment: Another observation, when I decrease the duration, I'm able to run the animation for 7 times and then it hangs 8th time. I guess it could be something related to duration as well.